# Fragment not attached to a context

Tags: android, android-fragments

In activity, in the Toolbar, I have a button that needs to call a method from a fragment and update the list in that fragment. Now it has an error.
Calling in activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case  R.id.menu_sort:
            ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
            listFragment.sortByPopularity();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Fragment code. I have found an error when Activity not attached. But nothing with context

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements ListAdapter.ItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Needed
     */
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View view;
    List<BasePojo.Result> list;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;

    public ListFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /**
         * Main Initialization
         */
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_list_detailed);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(list, setOnItemClickCallback());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        RetrofitClient.getApiService().getPhotosList(getString(R.string.api_key)).enqueue(new Callback<BasePojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasePojo> call, Response<BasePojo> response) {
                BasePojo basePojo = response.body();
                list.addAll(basePojo.getResults());
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BasePojo> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("tag", "Response failed" + t.toString());

            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Log.v("in on click", "value " + position);

    }

    private OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback setOnItemClickCallback() {
        OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback = new OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
                BasePojo.Result itemClicked = list.get(position);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("title", itemClicked.getOriginalTitle());
                bundle.putString("overview", itemClicked.getOverview());
                bundle.putString("release_date", itemClicked.getReleaseDate());
                bundle.putString("vote_average", itemClicked.getVoteAverage().toString());
                bundle.putString("poster_path", itemClicked.getPosterPath());
                DetailedFragment detailedFragment = new DetailedFragment();
                detailedFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_list, detailedFragment);
                Log.d("tag", "title is 111 " + bundle.get("title"));

                transaction.commit();
            }

        };
        return onItemClickCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);

    }

    public void sortByPopularity() {
        RetrofitClient.getApiService().getPopularList(getString(R.string.api_key)).enqueue(new Callback<BasePojo>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<BasePojo> call, Response<BasePojo> response) {
                BasePojo basePojo = response.body();
                list.addAll(basePojo.getResults());
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<BasePojo> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("tag", "Response failed" + t.toString());

            }
        }); }

}
```

And here is an error

```
05-09 12:48:26.915 5775-5775/com.borisruzanov.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.borisruzanov.popularmovies, PID: 5775
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ListFragment{6dbd6de} not attached to a context.
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:614)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:678)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:700)
    at com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.ListFragment.sortByPopularity(ListFragment.java:110)
    at com.borisruzanov.popularmovies.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:47)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3204)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:407)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
    at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$2.onMenuItemClick(ToolbarActionBar.java:63)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$1.onMenuItemClick(Toolbar.java:203)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView$MenuBuilderCallback.onMenuItemSelected(ActionMenuView.java:780)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:624)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:150)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Thank you very much for your time and help. If my question looks not well, please make a note and I will learn how to ask questions better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23854864/9025311

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a fragment instance is not enough. 
It needs to be attached to Activity through a transaction:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container_layout, fragment)
    .commit();
```

After a successful commit, `onAttach` method in the fragment is called, the view is created and then you can interact with its views.

In your case, create the fragment instance and attach it in activity `onCreate`, then call `sortByPopularity` later in a click event.

Read more about fragment life cycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: I have added it with fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_frame_list, fragment); But to call method i would need to create instance. Maybe here is the problem?

Comment: Why create a new instance? Attach the fragment but keep its reference. But please put the code where you attach the fragment

Comment: You attach `DetailedFragment` to the `ListFragment`, but `ListFragment` is not attached to the activity yet. And another thing, `DetailFragment` should be attached using `getSupportChildFragmentManager` because it's a child of `ListFragment`.

Answer (score 121):

In my case, this problem occurred when I was calling `getString()`

changing this calls to `getActivity().getString()` solved the problem.

Comment: For me now it returns a "Null pointer exception" dont know why if the activity is still running

Comment: I applied a similar solution. I do `myview.getContext().getString(bla_bla_bla)` to solve this problem.

Comment: My issue occur inside a timer. This solved the problem. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It didn't fix the issue. But it gives a great idea where to look at. Thanks. Bdw fixed the original issue by checking Activity is finishing or not. Upvoting +10

Comment: Odd that this should work for people.  In the Fragment source, `getString()` and `getActivity()` both get their context from the same `FragmentHostCallback`.  It is possible to have a FragmentHostCallback with a non-null activity and a null context, but as far as I can tell, not the other way around.  Possibly things were different in another Android version.

Comment: To avoid non-null point exception, use requireActivity().getString(R.string.string_name);

Comment: With Kotlin, you can also use `activity?.getString`

Answer (score 30):

Using `commit()` can not solve the problem, we should try to find the solution in the source code of Fragment.

So, consider from the error stack you provided, the `requireContext()` in Fragment was:

```java
    public final Context requireContext() {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to a context.");
        }
        return context;
    }
```

This means the system will check the `Context` from `getContext()`, if it's null, the exception will be thrown.

So, to avoid this problem, we can check the result of `getContext()` before do our business.

Comment: if context == null; how do you attach the fragment the context...?

Comment: But if I define some actions and the context is null, then the behavior is not the expected. For example i want to change some text in a text view and the context is null it won't change. How can I solve this?

Comment: @JorgeAlejandroPuñales The fragment might be in abnormal state at this moment, so it might be unecessary to perform the action. To add context == null check is mainly used to avoid crash at runtime.

Comment: we could also try to use global context to get string and other resources

Comment: seems fragment.isAdded() doesnt work flawlessly. using getContext() as added condition helps to be safer.

Answer (score 21):

Kotlin:

My problem happened with `getString()`

Changing it to `context.getString()` solved it

Comment: getContext() and getActivity() are both Nullable and will get this crash again

Comment: Kotlin devs use activity?.getString()

Answer (score 16):

If you are using **CountDownTimer**, you may get that error cause of detaching the fragment before finishing the timer. If you are performing ui changes in **onFinish** callback, you should check the context that it is null or not like below;

```
    timer = object : CountDownTimer(startTimeInMillis, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            context?.let {
              //perform ui changes here 
            }
        }
    }
    timer?.start()
```

or you should cancel the timer before detaching fragment like below;

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    timer?.cancel()
}
```

Comment: This was my situation... +1 because the OP was not related to CountDownTimer, but the error is the same.

Comment: yeah in Kotlin, using `context?.let {}` is a pretty simple fix

Answer (score 9):

If a fragment is not shown (not added) or is removed, it's `context == null`. In this case getting resources will lead to this exception. `getString(R.string.some_string)` requires `context` and crashes.

You can check whether the fragment exists so:

```
if (isAdded) {
    // Print getString(R.string.some_string).
}
```

But you might need to print the string even when the fragment was released, for instance, in LogCat, analytics or send a request to a server. In this case you need an application context to obtain a string resource.

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        instance = this
    }


    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: MyApplication private set
    }
}

object Strings {
    fun get(@StringRes stringRes: Int, vararg formatArgs: Any = emptyArray()): String {
        return instance.getString(stringRes, *formatArgs)
    }
}
```

Then set `MyApplication` in AndroidManifest and use: `Strings.get(R.string.some_string)`.

Answer (score 5):

For everybody who still have this error:

```
private Context mContext;    

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mContext = context;
}
```

And do not add  `mContext = null` in `onDetach` method 'cause you will still get this error.

Answer (score 4):

For kotlin developers

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
// do your work here 
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer as the answer does not specify how it relates to the question neither explains how it's going to solve problem or how can the code be used more specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin : Use Lazy Initialisation

```
override val contentMessage by lazy {
     getString(R.string.message)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This assertion can occur anywhere you have a `requireContext()` call to get access to the Android context from your Fragment. Review the call site carefully, before you use `requireContext()`. I only use `requireContext()` when I'm certain that the fragment is going to be attached to the Activity at the time or the use case is so essential that it is better to crash with this assertion than any other course of action.

If for any reason the fragment could happen to be unattached and you can handle it yourself at the call site by avoiding or early returning, then the better idea is to null check the return from `getContext()` and only then proceed forward.

Typical Kotlin code for the null check looks like this:

```
fun myFragmentFunction(){
    val context = getContext() ?: return // early return using Elvis operator
    context.whatever() // guaranteed non-null context at this point
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I just figured out what you could do. It is true that creating a fragment instance is not enough, It needs to be attached to Activity through a transaction. However, you can initially add both fragments and detach them from fragment manager. That way, they are both 'alive' in fragmentManager and  you can call attach and detach on those fragments later as you wish.

i.e

```
.add(container, fragment1).detach(fragment1).add(container, fragment2).commit();
.
.
.
.
.
ft.detach(fragment2)
ft.attach(fragment1
```

Answer (score 2):

As Tam Huynh said, this crash happens when we our fragment is not attached. I had the same problem that your (but with a bottomSheet) and now it works fine.

We can receive this kind of error from two reasons:

- `requireContext()` can crash directly if the context is null
- Calling `getString(R.string.xxx_xxx_xxx)` from fragment will crash if the fragment is detached (because we will need the context and the context is null).

For me, with that piece of code we can check if our fragment is attached or not, and with that I solve the crash.

```
fun checkIfFragmentAttached(operation: Context.() -> Unit) {
        if (isAdded && context != null) {
            operation(requireContext())
        }
    }
```

More info => https://weidianhuang.medium.com/android-fragment-not-attached-to-a-context-24d00fac4f3d

Answer (score 1):

```java
if (getActivity() != null){
    textkol_PC.setBackground(
        requireActivity().getResources()
        .getDrawable(R.drawable.background_close, null)
    );
}
```

Comment: There are **16 existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted answer with over **one hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario validate if you don't have any class level properties which are dependent on context as the fragment is not committed it won't have the context and we might end up with this exception.

Answer (score 0):

AVOID using getActivity(), getContext()
USE activity.getresources().getString("string") instead
INITIALIZE activity instance in TWO places:

1. contructor
   `if(context instance of Activity) this.activity = (activity)context;`
2. onAttach() callback:
   `if(context instance of Activity) this.activity = (activity)context;`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this problem when setting a textview's color using `textview.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,ColorRes(int)))`

Using `binding.root.context` as a context solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

before creating and swapping fragments check savedInstanceState and return

```java
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  return;
}
```

source: https://tech.auct.eu/solved-fragment-not-attached-to-a-context/