# Android Kotlin: Fragment not attached to a context

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-context

I am trying to use a TabLayout with different fragments and have started with AndroidStudio's automatically generated code for the tabbed layout. I have not changed how the placeholder fragment is created, displayed, handled etc.: The fragment is handled by a FragmentPagerAdapter, which is used by a ViewPaper, which in turn is used to setup the TabLayout.

The layout already included a FAB. Its onClick looks like this:

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    val currentFragment: Fragment = sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(viewPager.currentItem)
    when (viewPager.currentItem) {
        0 -> doSomething()
        1 -> (currentFragment as PlaceholderFragment).fabOnClick()
        else -> doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

Eventhough the above code makes sure that `fabOnClick()` is only called on the currently visible fragment, when I am trying to get a context using `requireContext()` in the PlaceholderFragment, java throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PlaceholderFragment{660c58b} (08f94c5f-64b3-4a50-a1d4-2f3a6c7b491c)} not attached to a context.
```

For some reason, the context *is* available in e.g. `onResume()` in the PlaceholderFragment:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    // Works fine
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "placeholder", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

fun fabOnClick() {
    // Throws exception
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "placeholder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

I found this thread, [Fragment not attached to a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257505/fragment-not-attached-to-a-context), in which the solution was to commit a fragment transaction but all of this seems to be handled automatically in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed an error somewhat similar to you in my code. ***With the same error you are getting.***
The idea is that I was initializing a string variable (***NOT in MainActivity***) with getResources().
However, the variable was not being initialized with context.getResources()

I was able to initialize this variable inside MainActivity and make it static so that I could just copy the value into the variable **NOT inside MainActivity**.

So, I think you should search for any variables that you are initializing with getResources and see if you are using a context or not.