# Kotlin fragment : activity returns null outside onActivityCreated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to use `startActionMode` inside a fragment.

`startActionMode` works fine in the `onActivityCreated` method. But outside `onActivityCreated` method, activity returns null and hence `activity?.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback)` doesn't work.

```
package com.akshat.music
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_songs.*
import java.io.File


class SongsFragment : Fragment(), SongListAdapter.OnItemClickListener{

private val allSongs = ArrayList<Songs>()
var activityRef: FragmentActivity? = null


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    activityRef = activity;
    if (activityRef == null)
        Log.d("MIKE", " $activityRef is empty");
    else
        Log.d("MIKE", " $activityRef is not empty");
    recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        adapter = SongListAdapter(allSongs, SongsFragment().apply { this@SongsFragment })
    }
    activity?.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback) // works

}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    getAudioDirectories()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs, container, false);
}

override fun onItemClicked(song: Songs, position: Int) {
    if (activityRef == null)
        Log.d("MIKE", " $activityRef is empty");
    else
        Log.d("MIKE", " $activityRef is not empty");
    activity?.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback)  // doesn't work
    activityRef?.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback) // activityRef is null
}

private val mActionModeCallback: ActionMode.Callback =
    object : ActionMode.Callback {
        override fun onCreateActionMode(
            actionMode: ActionMode,
            menu: Menu
        ): Boolean {
            val menuInflater = actionMode.menuInflater
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_action_bar, menu)
            return true
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(
            actionMode: ActionMode,
            menu: Menu
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(
            actionMode: ActionMode,
            menuItem: MenuItem
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(actionMode: ActionMode) {
            var actionMode: ActionMode? = actionMode
            actionMode = null
        }
    }

private fun getAudioDirectories() {
    /////////////
    }
}
}
```

How can I get reference to activity outside `onActivityCreated` method?
Thanks

Comment: To get Activity inside androidx.fragment you should use `requireActivity()` method. It's return activity if fragment attach to activity.
It's strange why in you get `null` in `onItemClicked` Maybe you call this method from  `getAudioDirectories` i.e. Before call `onAttach()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get a reference to the activity from anywhere inside a fragment.
there are some cases where activity can be null e.g inside **onDetach()** or inside **OnCreateView()**, so **activity** doesn't always require a value.

try to use the requireContext() like Stachu has mentioned:

```
    (requireContext() as Activity).startActionMode(mActionModeCallback)
```

Comment: Thanks, but on using this, I get error as : Fragment SongsFragment{da808fa (17ea0969-4885-4eb9-a8f1-4776ad2521a4)} not attached to an activity

Comment: m.. that's strange.

Comment: try to use the **onAttach()** way:
`override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        activityRef = (context as MainActivity)
    }`

Answer (score 0):

you can cast context as Activity and call it from there, e.g.

```
override fun onItemClicked(song: Songs, position: Int) {
    ...
    (requireContext() as Activity).startActionMode(mActionModeCallback)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but on using this, I get error as :
`Fragment SongsFragment{da808fa (17ea0969-4885-4eb9-a8f1-4776ad2521a4)} not attached to an activity.`

Comment: how do you inflate this fragment? if done properly it should be attached to activity, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257505/fragment-not-attached-to-a-context

Comment: I have used following code :
`private fun showSongsFragment() {
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = SongsFragment()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }`

Comment: and you call that from the Activity, correct? Or maybe from other Fragment? how do you instantiate `manager`?

Comment: I'm calling it from Activity