# When the activity was recreated and reinitiate ViewPager2, the requireContext() and requireView() is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

When the Font Size is changed in the setting app of the Android device, the activity is recreated. At that time, when the function of the fragment is accessed from the activity, the requireContext() and requireView() is null and viewModel is not initiated.

This is my code

Activity

```
    var pagerAdapter: NewPagerAdapter? = null
    fun initView(){
        val vpContent = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.vp_content)
        val fragmentList = ArrayList<ParentFragment>()
        fragmentList.add(FristFragment())
        fragmentList.add(SecondFragment())
        fragmentList.add(ThirdFragment())
        pagerAdapter = NewPagerAdapter(fragmentList, supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        vpContent.adapter = pagerAdapter

        val btnRefresh = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_scm_refresh)
        btnRefresh.setOnClickListener {
            (pagerAdapter)!!.allRefreshPage()
        }
    }
```

Adapter

```
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }

    fun allRefreshPage(context: Context){
        for(i in 0 until fragmentList.size){
            fragmentList[i].refreshData()
        }
    }
```

ParentFragment

```
abstract class ParentFragment : Fragment() {
    abstract fun refreshData()
}
```

ChildFragment

```
    private lateinit var viewModel: NewViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelFactory())[NewViewModel::class.java]
    }


    override fun refreshData() {
        if(context == null || view == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "refreshData: have not context or view")
            return
        }
        viewModel.initAppList(requireContext(), requireView())
    }
```

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I make sure that null doesn't come out?
3. Is there any other way to approach it as a function of the fragment in the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1/ Why is this happening?**

The PagerAdapter's fragmentList only saves the Fragment instance to set the data when needed, it should not use the fragment variable to update the UI. Although the Fragment is initiated, it's not being attached to the Activity yet (the user hasn't scrolled the tab to the position). If `Fragment` is not attached, `getContext` or `getActivity` are always null

Your `ViewModel` may not be created in the right position, as stated in the Fragment's onCreate document:

> Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is still in
> the process of being created. As such, you can not rely on things like
> the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized at this point

Read [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257505/fragment-not-attached-to-a-context/50257662#50257662)

**2/ How can I make sure that null doesn't come out?**

As I said, don't use the Fragment list in the Adapter to update your Fragment's data which may trigger a UI update. Always make sure any call to update the UI and require Context are after onViewCreated, you will have non-null Context between `onViewCreated` and `onDestroyView`

**3/ Is there any other way to approach it as a function of the fragment in the activity?**

a/ You should use `by activityViewModels` delegate to create the ViewModel to avoid creating the ViewModel in the wrong position, and `activityViewModels` will make sure your ViewModel is attached to the Activity instance, both Activity and Fragment give you the same ViewModel instance so you can share the data to between `Activity` and `Fragment`

```
private val viewModel by activityViewModels<TextClassifyViewModel>()
```

b/ Store your data in a `LiveData` inside `ViewModel`, then observe it from the `Fragment`. This way each time the Fragment is recreated, `LiveData` will fire the data again to keep the View up-to-date. No need to call `refreshData` every time.

Comment: First of all, I fixed it using Broadcast. I should try using LiveData. Thank you so much